# angular routing when using express

Tags: angularjs, express

I am using express to serve angular pages:

```
app.get('/settings', function(req, res){
        res.render('settings.ejs');
    });
```

Should I also be using the angular routeProvider? What is the point of it in an Express app (if any)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Angular route provider should be used if you're developing an angular app. Angular is an MVC and designed to be a full package solution. If you use express to provide routing you'll have to declare you're application on every page and include all the necessary js files.